# passing angular variable to razor function call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, razor

Somewhere in my angularjs controller, i have this variable:

```
$scope.variableForRazor = "Test Value For RAZOR!";
```

I want this variable to be passed as parameter when calling C# function via razor. Here's the simplified c# code:

```
public static string ShowMessage(string msg)
{
    return msg;
}
```

in razor:

```
@CSharpMethod.ShowMessage("{{variableForRazor}}")
```

the problem is that the value passed was `{{variableForRazor}}` itself.

How can I modify it so when I set a breakpoint on `ShowMessage`, the value that will be pass is `Test Value For RAZOR!`.

I tried also the following but does not work.

```
@CSharpMethod.ShowMessage("variableForRazor")
@CSharpMethod.ShowMessage({{variableForRazor}}) // does not compile
@CSharpMethod.ShowMessage(variableForRazor) // does not compile
```

Comment: You are asking a very good question... how to leverage your Razor values and pass them seamlessly to Angular without making a round-trip. One way is to have a hidden <input value="@Model.message" ng-model="variableForRazor ">` I know this doesn't seem elegant, but its a direct route into angular `$scope`. Another way is to use ng-init like `<div class="row-fluid" ng-controller="PersonDetailsController" ng-init="personId=@Model.Id">`

Answer (score -1):

You are mixing client and server code. AngularJS runs completely on your client. ASP.NET MVC on your server. If you want to pass information to your server to influence the generated Razor view, you have to include it in your server request as parameter (for GET requests) or in the request body

Comment: would you mind sharing a sample snippet? or a useful article? :)

Comment: boindiil, I think you miss the point. OP wants to pass Razor Model Values to his Angular App. This is more efficient than making another round trip to a service.

Comment: For me it looks like OP wants to pass the value of the angular variable `variableForRazor` to the razor method. @Pedigree could you please clear this?

Answer (score -1):

you've missed the point of client-server protocol.

if the `@CSharpMethod.ShowMessage` responsible for conditional display (eg. HTML, Css styling) try angular ng-hide/ng-show instead (try some [tutorial here](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/how-to-use-ngshow-and-nghide)).

if you really need javascript variable to be process on server side. use $http ajax to send information back to Asp.net MVC Controller

```
$http.post(@Url.Action("YourApi"), {variable: $scope.variable})
                .success(function(data) {
                    $scope.status = "done";
                })
                .error(function(data, status, header) {
                    $scope.status = "error";
                });
```

in your controller create Action to handle request

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult YourApi(string variable)
    {
        var result = DoSomething(variable);

        return Json(result);
    }
```

Comment: I think you miss the point. OP wants to pass Razor Model Values to his Angular App. This is more efficient than making another round trip to a service.